# jQuery : Change color of row in tables?

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-ui

I have a slight different requirement. Please don't mark it as duplicate.
I have two tables that are perfectly aligned to each other. Now, when i click on a specific row of a table for eg: the first row. The first row in the table should turn green and also the first row in the other table should also turn green as i said both the tables are aligned but they are two separate tables.

```
$('#myTable1').bind('click', function(e) {
  $(e.target).closest('tr').children('td,th').css('background-color','#000');
});
```

The above code will help me turn the color of my first table row to green but if I want the second table first row as well to turn green when I click on the first row of first table how can I do?

Comment: [`.index()`](https://learn.jquery.com/using-jquery-core/understanding-index/) and [`:nth-child()`](https://api.jquery.com/nth-child-selector/)

Comment: Where is your html code?

Comment: Do want the row of your second table to be changed only when the first table is clicked or when either table is clicked? Does your table have a header or just a body? `#000` is not green, did you mean `#0F0` or `green`?

Comment: @Twisty : When i click on the first row of my first table the first row of my first table gets changed to green. Alongwith that i want the first row of my second table also to get changed to green. Same with other rows of the table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Get the index of the clicked row by

```
`var index = $("table1 tr").index(this);`
```

And apply to another table like this

```
`$("table2 tr:nth-child("+index+")").css('background', 'green')`
```